# Operation on lists within Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have lists within a Pandas column.

I'd like to perform an operation on that column with a lambda function.

It shows an error and I don't understand why.

Appreciate any help.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats


df=pd.DataFrame({'indx':[1,2], 'vals':[[822.0, 855.0, 837.0],[692.0, 758.0, 818.0]]})


#Works
stats.linregress([1,2,3], [1,2,3])

#Works
df.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([1,2,3], [1,2,3]))

#Works
df.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([1,2,3], [822.0, 855.0, 837.0]))


#Fails
df.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([1,2,3], np.array(x).astype(np.float)))


#Harder example
df2=pd.DataFrame({'indx':[1,2], 'vals':[[822.0, 855.0],[692.0, 758.0, 818.0, 855.0, 837.0]]})
df2.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([i for i in range(1,len(x)+1)], np.array(x).astype(np.float)))
```

Comment: Run against `axis=1` or directly in `df.vals.apply(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly indexing the column `vals` and apply to `axis=1`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([1,2,3], x['vals']), axis=1)
```

[out]

```
0    (7.5, 823.0, 0.4539206495016018, 0.70004990665...
1    (63.0, 630.0, 0.9996222851612186, 0.0174980968...
dtype: object
```

and

```
df2.apply(lambda x: stats.linregress(np.arange(1, len(x['vals']) + 1), x['vals']), axis=1)
```

[out]

```
0                         (33.0, 789.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
1    (38.7, 675.9, 0.9166087820733272, 0.0285434179...
dtype: object
```